# Incorrect number of parameters supplied for lambda declaration while building expression from object

Tags: c#, .net, lambda, expression

I have created a method which converts object to expression.

```
private Expression<Func<TDto, bool>> GetObjectAsExpression<TSearchDto, TDto>(TSearchDto searchDto)
    where TSearchDto : class where TDto : class
{
    List<ParameterExpression> parameterExpressions = new List<ParameterExpression>();
    Expression predicateBody = default(Expression);
    int nodeCount = 1;
    foreach (PropertyInfo property in searchDto.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance))
    {
        ParameterExpression parameterExpression =
            Expression.Parameter(typeof(TDto), $"node{nodeCount++}");
        parameterExpressions.Add(parameterExpression);

        Expression left = Expression.Property(parameterExpression, property.Name);
        Expression expression = Expression.Equal(left, Expression.Constant(property.GetValue(searchDto)));
        if (predicateBody == null)
        {
            predicateBody = expression;
        }
        else
        {
            predicateBody = Expression.And(predicateBody, expression);
        }
    }

    return Expression.Lambda<Func<TDto, bool>>(
        predicateBody,
        parameterExpressions
    );
}
```

Case 1: When I call this method with single property it works fine.

```
GetObjectAsExpression<object, TDto>(new { CaseNumber = "00100283900813414832"})
```

Case 2: When I call this method with 2 parameters it throws the error

```
GetObjectAsExpression<object, TDto>(new { CaseNumber = "00100283900813414832", WareHouse = "008" })
```

with the error

```
System.ArgumentException: 'Incorrect number of parameters supplied for lambda declaration'
```

I have also searched for a nuget package or the source that can accomplish this and more. Please suggest a solution or an existing package that does this and more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what your intention is with the whole `nodeCount` thing, but that's what's going wrong. There's only ever *one* parameter to the `Func` you are producing - a *single* `TDto` goes in and a `bool` comes out - so you shouldn't be passing a whole list of parameters to the predicate you build.

Also, for conciseness, if you start your predicate with `true`, you don't need that null check - you can just chain `And`s.

Doing both gives:

```
private Expression<Func<TDto, bool>> GetObjectAsExpression<TSearchDto, TDto>(TSearchDto searchDto)
    where TSearchDto : class where TDto : class
{
    ParameterExpression singleParameterExpression = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TDto), "node");

    Expression predicateBody = Expression.Constant(true);
    foreach (PropertyInfo property in searchDto.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance))
    {
        Expression left = Expression.Property(singleParameterExpression, property.Name);
        Expression expression = Expression.Equal(left, Expression.Constant(property.GetValue(searchDto)));
        predicateBody = Expression.And(predicateBody, expression);
    }

    return Expression.Lambda<Func<TDto, bool>>(
        predicateBody,
        singleParameterExpression
    );
}
```

which I think gives the result you want.

Comment: It is simple as that, which killed my hours and hours of work.

Comment: Trying to build generic repository and generic uow, which works with all the domain models. And also involves mapping Dtos to entities at run time. That's what my employer wants. He believes he can save tonnes of time and work by building these two pieces.